# How to retrieve an image from web generated from a php script

Tags: php, python, image, captcha

Basically I want to programmatically retrieve an image (captcha) generated by a PHP script from the projecteuler.net site, for automation purpose.

[image]

How can I do that?

Here is the code from the html source

```
<img src="captcha/show_captcha.php" id="captcha_image" onclick="javascript:this.src='captcha/show_captcha.php?'+Math.random();" style="border:1px solid #999;" /><br />Click image for new code
```

Comment: This question is Not related to Python **`:)`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to do it programmatically in PHP: Use a simple web spider tool (e.g. http://www.sphider.eu/) or any other method to access the DOM and fetch the image that way. 
Here is a post that offers a solution that might fit your bill:
https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/340460/php-image-crawlerspider